# Словообразование в русском языке

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, почему слово "ремесленник" образованно не от "ремесло", а от "ремесленный"? От учителей слышал, что сначала появляется прилагательное, а затем существительное. Однако в интернете написано, что существительное может быть образовано почти от любой части речи. Какое правило здесь работает?

Comment: **Илья**, Вас продолжает интересовать ответ на заданный Вами вопрос? Если да, то откликнитесь, пожалуйста. У меня есть материал, подтверждающий возможность образования слова «ремесленник» не только от прилагательного  «ремесленный», но и  от существительного «ремесло».

Answer (score 2):

В этой теме много **условностей.**

1. Возьмем слово ***лесник.*** У Тихонова: *лес — лесник,* суффикс ***НИК***. А почему не *лес — лесной — лесник?*

В толковом словаре: **ЛЕСНИК,** -а; м. **Лесной** сторож; работник **лесного** хозяйства.

Но существует суффикс ***НИК,*** обозначающий профессию, хотя фактически это **составной** суффикс: Н (суффикс прилагательного)  + ИК (суффикс существительного).

2. Возьмем слово ***ремесленник***. У Тихонова: *ремесло — ремесленный — ремесленник.* Но почему не *ремесло — ремесленник*. В толковом словаре:

**РЕМЕСЛЕННИК**, -а; м. 1. Лицо, знающее какое-л. **ремесл**о (1 зн.) и занимающееся по заказу потребителя изготовлением изделий кустарным способом собственными орудиями производства. Мелкий р. Частный р. Сословие ремесленников.

У нас нет суффикса ***ЕННИК***? Есть, в словаре Ефремовой он указан, но как нерегулярный: *путешествовать — путешественник*, образование от глагола.

Нет значит нет. Ориентируемся на словарь Тихонова: **ремесло — ремесленный — ремесленник**. По семантике не так, но в данном случае важнее существующие словообразовательные **модели**.